# in shell scripting (bash), how does tail work for continuously updated file?

Tags: bash, tail

i have a file that is being continuously updated with.
everytime i call `tail file.log` it will show a different result.

My question is, how do it work under the hood ?
i would expect that it reads the file from the bytes backwards, but meanwhile it is being continuously udpated. how does it work without corrupting the file, and yet display a uncorrupted result ?

Everytime i google `How does tail work for continuously updated file`,
i get solutions on how to monitor it with `tail -f file.log`, which i know it works.

But what i want to know is how it works.

Comment: Read [the source](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src) and find out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The `man tail` in every searchengine should link it to [tail(1)](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) and explain this if you read further whatfore the option `-s` is.

Answer (score 0):

> i would expect that it reads the file from the bytes backwards, but meanwhile it is being continuously udpated. how does it work without corrupting the file, and yet display a uncorrupted result ?

Every open file has an associated *file offset* associated with an open *file descriptor* (see `man 2 lseek`, `man 3 lseek` and `man open` and file descriptor on wikipedia).

When the *file offset* is positioned at the end of the file (points *past* the last character in the file) the *system call* for reading more data from the file will "block" (see `man 3 read`) (or in case of `O_NONBLOCK` will return with zero bytes read, but let's say we ignore that case).

The *file descriptor* will be blocked for reading until new data are written to the file. The process is blocked - all logic is implemented in the kernel. Let's say the kernel has a list of "waiting" processes that wait for new events on a file. When some other process writes new data to the end of the file, kernel goes through waiting processes on the end of the file and kernel wakes those processes up.

When the process is woken up, `read()` call can finally read available data. `read()` returns the new data, moves *file offset*, and the process continues its work.

When reading from multiple files, there is a special *system call* that allows to wait for "new data" on multiple *file descriptors*. See `man -a select` and `man poll`.